# Unititalized variable error

Tags: c

Problem: I am doing an assignment that seems pretty straightforward, however, I am getting an error that says variable 'test1' is uninitialized. I declared it as an int, then initialized it in the scanf statement. any help here?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

void main()
{
int hours, hours2, test1, test2, test3, avg, well;
avg = (test1 + test2 + test3) / 3;

printf("Enter your Cprogram Test grades here for Test 1, 2, and 3: \n");
scanf("%d%d%d", &test1, &test2, &test3);
printf("The average of these grades are: %d. \n", avg);
```

Comment: See [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336) for a discussion of why there are only a few places where `void main()` is legitimate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used the variable `test1` in the line

```
avg = (test1 + test2 + test3) / 3;
```

which comes *before* the scanf.  So `test1` (and likewise `test2` and `test3`) were uninitialized when used at that time.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation of `avg = (test1 + test2 + test3) / 3;` which references test1 needs to occur after you initialize it by reading from scanf. Move that line after `scanf("%d%d%d", &test1, &test2, &test3);` and it will work:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

void main()
{
int hours, hours2, test1, test2, test3, avg, well;


printf("Enter your Cprogram Test grades here for Test 1, 2, and 3: \n");
scanf("%d%d%d", &test1, &test2, &test3);
avg = (test1 + test2 + test3) / 3;
printf("The average of these grades are: %d. \n", avg);

}
```

C,C++, like most procedural languages evaluates your code in the order in which it is written. That is, `avg = (test1 + test2 + test3) / 3;` assigns a value to avg based on the current values of test1,test2 and test3. These must be defined and initialized before the assignment is performed. That is what `scanf("%d%d%d", &test1, &test2, &test3);` does.

Comment: You're right.  The code should also check that `scanf()` was able to read three integers successfully — you'll still use uninitialized variables if if fails to read all three.